# Update from PHP 5 to PHP 7.0 - PHPmyAdmin will show two server logins: localhost / localhost:3306

Tags: mysql, php, phpmyadmin, users

I updated my Linux 14.04 LTS to 18.04 and had to downgrade the PHP 7.2 to 7.0 as I need to run some software which is not capable of the preinstalled PHP 7.2. I used PHP 5 so far.

After I got everything runnning now, MySQL, Apache and PHP I created a new database and now I get a Notification that the control user can't be connected and that 'pmp'@localhost has denied access.

This appears when I log into server @ localhost.

If I choose localhost:3306 everything works fine. But I do not know why I have two server logins?

I'm somehow confused, that I get two servers to choose from (localhost and localhost:3066) which I would not have expected. Can I somehow delete the localhost-access for PHPmyAdmin and only enable localhost:3306?

Any idea what I have to do? I'm a database newbie. Best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I comment these lines in my config.inc.php, everything runs like expected and I'll get only one server account where I can login.

```
/**
 * phpMyAdmin configuration storage settings.
 */

/* User used to manipulate with storage */
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlhost'] = '';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlport'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = 'pmapass';

/* Storage database and tables */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma__bookmark';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma__relation';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma__table_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma__table_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma__pdf_pages';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma__column_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma__history';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma__table_uiprefs';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma__tracking';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma__userconfig';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['recent'] = 'pma__recent';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['favorite'] = 'pma__favorite';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['users'] = 'pma__users';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['usergroups'] = 'pma__usergroups';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['navigationhiding'] = 'pma__navigationhiding';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['savedsearches'] = 'pma__savedsearches';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['central_columns'] = 'pma__central_columns';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_settings'] = 'pma__designer_settings';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['export_templates'] = 'pma__export_templates';
/* Contrib / Swekey authentication */
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_swekey_config'] = '/etc/swekey-pma.conf';
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to connect to the `mysql` on the localhost. One is the connection via network `@localhost:3306` and another is the connection through the filesocket like `/tmp/mysql.sock`. Filesocket connection is preferred due to the lower overhead and mysql library choose it if available when connection to the localhost requested. I have no clue why they are separated now.

If you want to connect to the mysql only locally then networking can be disabled completely in the `my.cnf` so all connections are forced to be filesocket-based. That is also a bit more secure as far as no one can connect to the mysql over the network.

Comment: @Kodybas Actually this is not related to my question and does not give an answer anyhow.

Comment: @Hirschferkel What is returned by `select user, host from mysql.user;` query?

Comment: @Kodybas I think the standard: | root | 127.0.0.1 | | root | ::1 | | debian-sys-maint | localhost | | mysql.session | localhost | | mysql.sys | localhost | | phpmyadmin | localhost | | root | localhost |